# How do I automatically run a function after manually saving a buffer in Emacs Lisp in a particular mode?

Tags: emacs

I would like to run `untabify` on the current buffer on manually saving the buffer.  Is there an easy way using Emacs Lisp to run this function as a on-save-hook for `elm-mode`?

This did not work:

```
(when (eq (print major-mode) "elm-mode")
   (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'untabify))
```

Comment: Specify what you mean by "did not work".

Comment: I meant to say that it did not run `untabify` after saving in `elm-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code you posted cannot work, because (assuming it is written exactly like this in your init file), it will run when Emacs starts; at this point, `major-mode` is most likely not `elm-mode` and so no hook gets added.

Then: `print` does not *return* a string. It prints a string, and `returns` what it was passed as argument. In that case, `major-mode` is a symbol. To check if the current major-mode is elm-mode, you would do `(eq major-mode 'elm-mode)`, effectively comparing symbols.
As a side note, `eq` is  not suitable for string comparison, use `string=` or `string-equal`.

What you would do is add a hook to `after-save-hook` without condition, and check inside the hook whether or not you should perform the action:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda ()
                             (when (eq major-mode 'elm-mode)
                               (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

You need to give arguments to `untabify`. In that case, it simply untabifies the whole buffer.

Another way would be to add a buffer local hook, using something like

```
(add-hook 'elm-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (add-hook 'after-save-hook <my-function> nil t)))
```

As always: see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html), accessible from within Emacs in `info` mode, using `describe-function` on `add-hook`, and so on. In general, you will learn *a lot* if you start by trying to check the built-in documentation.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the final version that worked for me based on your suggestions above:

(add-hook 'elm-mode-hook (lambda ()
          (message "Adding the untabify after save hook")
      (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda ()
       (untabify (point-min) (point-max)) nil t))))